# $ \forall n=1,2,\cdots,b_n:=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin nx \mathrm{d}x\geq0 $

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f$ be a periodic function with period $2\pi$. Suppose $f$ is integrable. If $f$ is monotone decreasing on $(0,2\pi)$. Prove that
> $$
> \forall n=1,2,\cdots,b_n:=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin nx \mathrm{d}x\geq0
> $$

I tried to use mean value theorems for definite integrals. Write $m:=\inf_{[0,2\pi]}f$,then
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin nx \mathrm{d}x=[f(-\pi)-m]\int_{-\pi}^{\xi_1}\sin nx\mathrm{d}x+[f(0)-m]\int_{0}^{\xi_2}\sin nx\mathrm{d}x
$$
The second term is always $\geq 0$, but the first term may be negative for even $n$, so I stuck here.

How should I go on? Also you can suggest your own way. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Presumably, the question means monotone decreasing on some interval, maybe $[-\pi,\pi]?$ The only periodic functions which are monotone are constants.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I mistyped. It shoule be ''If f is monotone decreasing on $(-\pi,\pi)$".

Comment: Are you missing a hypothesis somewhere? If $f$ is equal to $1$ on $(-\pi, 0)$, and equal to $0$ on $(0, \pi)$, then the result is false.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped again. It should be "decreasing on $(0,2\pi)$".